# What's the proper way to use IF condition in Laravel Blade file?

Tags: laravel, if-statement, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Table Header:

```
@if($products->subcategory->name == 'Image')
  <th>Demo</th>
@else

@endif
```

Table Column under forelse loop:

```
@forelse ($products as $item)
  <tr>
      @if($item->subcategory->name == 'Image')
         <td>
            <p>{{$item->surl}}</p>
         </td>
        @else
      @endif 
 </tr>
@endforelse
```

The problem is: IF condition works inside the forelse loop but not working outside.
I want to hide/show a column if the subcategory name is "Image".

what's the proper way for writing this condition.

Comment: What is $products? Is it an array? If it is an array then you who find the index like `$products[0]->subcategory->name == "Image"`

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. You just save my life !

Comment: No worries.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$products` is an array then you can do it like this:

```
@foreach($products as $item)
 <tr>
  @if($item->subcategory->name == 'Image')
     <td>
        <p>{{$item->url}}</p>
     </td>
    @else
  @endif 
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

If you have any specific index in mind then you can do it like this:

```
@if(isset($products[2]) && ($products[2]->subcategory->name == "Image") 
<td>
        <p>{{$products[2]->url}}</p>
     </td>
@endif
```

It'll check if index 2 exists and there are many other ways to check the same as well. Once you have verified then you can go and check for the index.